# How to assign site for new user via Kentico API

Tags: c#, kentico, kentico-api

I'm trying to create a new Kentico user and assigning them to a site, via Kentico API: https://docs.kentico.com/api11/configuration/users#Users-Assigningausertoasite

In my case `SiteContext.CurrentSiteName` returns empty string. I thought of trying by hard coding the site.

```
UserInfor newUser = new UserInfo();
//...set all required properties...

//add user to site
UserInfoProvider.AddUserToSite(newUser.UserName, "My Site Code(or Display) Name");

//save user
UserInfoProvider.SetUserInfo(newUser);
```

Tried both Display Name as well as Code Name of the site in `UserInfoProvider.AddUserToSite`, but the user is not getting assigned to the site on Kentico site. It does get created with all the properties.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [SiteInfoProvider](https://docs.kentico.com/api11/configuration/sites) to get the site code name

```
var si = SiteInfoProvider.GetSites()
                         .WhereEquals("SiteId",123)
                         .FirstOrDefault();
UserInfoProvider.AddUserToSite(newUser.UserName, si.SiteName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had to add user to the site ***after*** saving the user.

```
//save user
UserInfoProvider.SetUserInfo(newUser);

//add user to site
UserInfoProvider.AddUserToSite(newUser.UserName, "My Site Code Name (not display name)");
```